# Mongo async threads fails randomly on security manager permission

Tags: java, mongodb, security

We use the Mongodb async driver 3.0.4 with RXJava and Vert.x to avoid blocking the event loop thread.

Our code to execute MongoDB looks like :

```
           myCollection.bulkWrite(myList, new SingleResultCallback<BulkWriteResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(BulkWriteResult bulkWriteResult, Throwable throwable) {
                    if (throwable == null) {
                        subscriber.onNext(bulkWriteResult.getInsertedCount());
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                        MyLogger.debug("Success"); 
                    } else {
                        MyException myException = new MyException(throwable);
                        subscriber.onError(myException);
                        MyLogger.error("Success"); 
                    }
                }
```

Sometimes, i've the exception hereafter.

For debugging, i add in the end of my java policy(default policy) file the line to allow all permission, but i changes no thing, i still have under some stress load the exception. And i've an other exception when Vert.x call the setContextClassLoader (exception in the message too).

```
  grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
  }
```

It happens only with Mongodb async threads. I use CXF in async mode, and everything is working fine. With mongodb, this problem is randomly.

Any help is welcomed.

Regards

```
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/var/logs/myLogFile.log" "read")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
        at java.io.File.length(File.java:969)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.isTriggeringEvent(SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.java:59)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:177)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:103)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:88)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.sift.SiftingAppenderBase.append(SiftingAppenderBase.java:111)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.AppenderBase.doAppend(AppenderBase.java:85)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:273)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:260)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:442)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_1(Logger.java:414)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:604)
      ..................................
      ..................................
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:53)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientImpl$2$2.onResult(MongoClientImpl.java:144)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:53)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper$ConnectionReleasingWrappedCallback.onResult(OperationHelper.java:140)
        at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$3.onResult(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:208)
        at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$3.onResult(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:187)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:53)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$1.onResult(DefaultServer.java:171)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:53)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol$1.onResult(InsertCommandProtocol.java:86)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol$1.onResult(InsertCommandProtocol.java:79)
        at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.executeBatchesAsync(WriteCommandProtocol.java:154)
        at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.access$000(WriteCommandProtocol.java:37)
        at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol$1.onResult(WriteCommandProtocol.java:145)
        at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol$1.onResult(WriteCommandProtocol.java:123)
        at com.mongodb.connection.CommandResultCallback.callCallback(CommandResultCallback.java:54)
```

setContextClassLoader exception :

```
   java.lang.SecurityException: setContextClassLoader
                at sun.misc.InnocuousThread.setContextClassLoader(InnocuousThread.java:64)
                at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext.setTCCL(DefaultContext.java:63)
                at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultVertx.setContext(DefaultVertx.java:325)
                at org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.impl.DefaultEventBus.sendOrPub(DefaultEventBus.java:743)
                at org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.impl.DefaultEventBus.sendOrPub(DefaultEventBus.java:670)
                at org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.impl.DefaultEventBus.sendReply(DefaultEventBus.java:528)
                at org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.impl.BaseMessage.sendReply(BaseMessage.java:348)
                at org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.impl.BaseMessage.reply(BaseMessage.java:156)
                at org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.impl.BaseMessage.reply(BaseMessage.java:76)
                .........................
                at rx.Observable$32.onNext(Observable.java:7187)
                at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:130)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.onNext(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:76)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:620)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:545)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:635)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:545)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:635)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:545)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                ...................
                at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:53)
                at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientImpl$2$2.onResult(MongoClientImpl.java:144)
                at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:53)
                at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper$ConnectionReleasingWrappedCallback.onResult(OperationHelper.java:140)
                at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$3.onResult(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:208)
                at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$3.onResult(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:187)
                at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:53)
                at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$1.onResult(DefaultServer.java:171)
                at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:53)
                at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol$1.onResult(InsertCommandProtocol.java:86)
                at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol$1.onResult(InsertCommandProtocol.java:79)
                at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.executeBatchesAsync(WriteCommandProtocol.java:154)
                at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.access$000(WriteCommandProtocol.java:37)
                at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol$1.onResult(WriteCommandProtocol.java:145)
                at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol$1.onResult(WriteCommandProtocol.java:123)
                at com.mongodb.connection.CommandResultCallback.callCallback(CommandResultCallback.java:54)
                at com.mongodb.connection.CommandResultCallback.callCallback(CommandResultCallback.java:29)
                at com.mongodb.connection.CommandResultBaseCallback.callCallback(CommandResultBaseCallback.java:39)
```

Comment: Vert.x appears to attempting to set the thread context class loader of a system thread. In this case the system thread will refuse in all circumstances. The file operation exception is presumably also in a system thread which has made the access control context safe.

Comment: But why i get this error once in a 1000 times, under heavy load ?

Comment: After trying to debug under a load test, putting breakpoint on class FilePermission(checkPermission method) where the method return false, i notice from the thread id of my thread pool that i've this problem with threads not created initially in my thread pool. So, i guess that when thread is not created in the initial context (context of my init application), and created by the pool in a CXF context, i've this problem. I guess that i need to create my own thread factory ? I tried the same stress test with a larger pool (min=max=20), and the problem disapear !! anybody help me to understand ?

Comment: It's not unusual for static initialisers to directly or indirectly create threads that inherit from whatever random thread context they happen to be in at the time. Lazy evaluation can behave similarly. The solution is to create threads in a known context and/or explicitly reset the thread (permissions, thread context class loader and group). Not necessarily so easy if the thread creation is buried inside some badly behaved library.